# Run another function once transaction has been completed

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I am trying to run a function that calls my API to update user info, including the number of coins the user has after a transaction has been made. I can't figure out how to do that. Here's my code for the transaction:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        
for transaction in transactions {

                switch transaction.transactionState {
                case .purchasing:
                    transactionState = .purchasing
                    print("Purchasing...")
                case .purchased:
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                    print("Purchased.")
                    if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
                        FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {
                        do {
                            let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                            let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                            Task {
                                await postCoins(receipt: receiptString)
                            }
                        }
                        catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
                    }
                    transactionState = .purchased
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                case .restored:
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    transactionState = .restored
                case .failed, .deferred:
                    print("Payment queue error:")
                    print(String(describing: transaction.error))
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                    transactionState = .failed
                default:
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                }
            }
    }
```

This function is inside an `SKProductsRequestDelegate`

I tried making this function async by adding a completion handler and then using `DispatchQueue.main.async` to update the thread where the payment is made, but it throws me an error saying that does not conform the that particular protocol. It makes sense that it threw that error, but I don't know another workaround.

Comment: There isn't any SwiftUI here -- this is just Swift

Comment: I realize that there is not SwiftUI functionality in the snippet of code that I shared. I was referring to the fact that this code exists in a SwiftUI project, hence I am looking for a solution compatible with that. But now that you removed "in SwiftUI", it leaves it ambiguous what kind of solution I am looking for.

Comment: Then maybe you should post code that reveals what the real problem is and make it clear why SwiftUI is relevant for this question.